# Mapping http response to typeScript object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7

I am trying to convert API response (json string array) to typescript object but not able to achieve . I tried to add map function but not able to use it properly.

Sample API response is ["Paris","London","New York"]

my City class is like this

```
export class City { Name:string; 
                    isAvailable: boolean;
                  }
```

My function

```
public getCities(queryId: string) : Observable<City[]> {
              const url = apiUrl;

              const response = this.http.get<string[]>(url)
                                   .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
             //how can i add map method here to convert String to City object?

              return response;

         }
```

I expect output like

```
[
  {Name:"Paris",isAvailable:true},
  {Name:"London",isAvailable:true}, 
  {Name:"New York",isAvailable:true}
]
```

Comment: `.pipe(map(response => response.map(name => { Name: name, isAvailable: true } as City)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to handle this within your RxJS pipeline, this is what you can do. We use the RxJS [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) operator to transform the response into an array of `City` objects.

```
public getCities(queryId: string) : Observable<City[]> {
  const url = apiUrl;

  return this.http.get<string[]>(url)                                
    .pipe(
      map((res) = {
        return res.map(name => ({
          Name: name,
          isAvailable: true,
        });
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError));   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll need a way to actually put those values in your class. Let's just accept those in the constructor.

```
export class City {
  Name: string; 
  isAvailable: boolean;

  constructor(name: string, isAvailable: boolean) {
    this.Name = name
    this.isAvailable = isAvailable
  }
}
```

Now, assuming `response` is your JSON string, then first you want to parse the JSON string and cast it to the format you expect (which is `string[]`).

Then map over it to create what you need.

```
const cities: string[] = JSON.parse(response)
const cityObjects = cities.map(name => new City(name, true))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map data automatically with a lightweight package called tapi.js

```
npm i -D tapi.js
```

And then you can map the object automatically in a lot of ways, since you are mapping JSON data you can do so as such

```
http.YOUR_REQUEST
    .as(YourClass)
    .[then/pipe/whatever](typedObject => { ... })
```

You can [read the docs](https://tapi.js.org) for more info.